# What should be the approach for finding the remainder

Tags: number-theory

How can one approach this kind of question: Find the remainder when $\left((7!)^{6!}\right)^{17777}$ is divided by 17

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic? DO you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know Fermat' Little Theoram, although not able to apply it over here. No idea about modular arithmetic.

Comment: Why are you not able to apply it here?

Comment: I tried again, this is what I did, 6! Leaves remainder 0 on dividing it by 16 (got from: 17*(1 - (1/17)) ), so now what left is [(7!)^0]^1777 , leaving remainder 1. not sure if its correct or not,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by Fermat's Little Theorem $a^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 17$ for every $a$ that is not $0$ modulo $17$.

Since $16 \mid 6!$ it follows that your expression is $1$ modulo $17$ if $7!$ is not $0$ modulo $17$, which is the case.